# How to retrieve "double strings" from a string

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

**Double String**:

We call a string a "double string" if it has an even length and the first half of this string is equal to the second half of this string, for example "abab" is a double string because the first half "ab" is equal to the second half "ab", however the string "abba" is not a double string because the first half "ab" is not equal to the second half "ba". The empty string "" is a double string, and its length is 0.

The question is :

**How to retrieve a max len double-string from a string in O(nlogn) time or even faster?**
where n is length of a string.

**Example**:

input : ababc

output: abab

I've found a source that states this problem. However, I haven't understood the paper yet. At least, it's a great resource to give everyone an answer.

please check the link below:
http://digitool.library.colostate.edu///exlibris/dtl/d3_1/apache_media/L2V4bGlicmlzL2R0bC9kM18xL2FwYWNoZV9tZWRpYS8xNjY2ODE=.pdf

Comment: Is the question to return all such double strings within the input?  The one of maximum length?  For instance what is the correct output for "ababababc"

Comment: This can be done using a regular expression with a back-reference.

Comment: Not in O(nlog(n)), though.

Comment: Hi,user2357112, I think the max len should be the answer. If all double strings needed, the Big-O should be bigger.

Comment: Barmar, can you elaborate it? or a link shared?

Comment: `(.*)\1` is a regex that will search for a double string, but it won't do so efficiently.

Comment: "abba" **is** a double string according to definition (output: "bb"). EDIT: @JuanLopes you're right, that's what I wanted to say and the definition actually doesn't negate it.

Comment: @Dariusz No, it isn't. It __contains__ a double string. "bb" is a double string.

Comment: Tried my best with suffix arrays, but didn't find an answer. The critical case for me is "abababab", where the suffix array would put "ababab" between "abab" and "abababab".

Comment: @JuanLopes Thanks Juan. Your solution of suffix arrays brings me some ideas. I'm trying to tackle the problem with it. I will definitely let you know the answer if I got one. Thanks again.

Comment: Please provide more examples of input and output. From this example it is not obvious whether the double string needs to be at the beginning of string or not.